# Powershell what's the difference between this 2 vars

Tags: powershell

I had an issue with select-string using `-notMatch` if I used this var `$searchVar = 'bla bla', 'la la'` I would get an error but once I changed it to `$searchVar = 'bla bla|la la'` it worked, what does the `|` do to the string?

Comment: The `|` symbol is the regex `OR` operator. PowerShell's `-match` and `-notmath` use Regex. By adding a comma as you tried, you are creating a string array

Comment: Works for me.  What is the actual command line?  `echo hi | select-string -NotMatch $searchVar`

Comment: @js2010 - the `Select-String` cmdlet accepts an array of patterns in the `-Pattern`  parameter. the OP didn't mention if the `-notmatch`  mentioned is an operator OR a switch-parameter.